# Suppress new line in ASP Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Update, wrapping in span doesn't fix the problem.

I feel like this should be easy but I can't find an answer anywhere. I have the code below that is bound to data in a gridview. Currently the Description evaluates and shows up as expected but then the Created By icon which Iwould like to show up right at the end of Description always drops down and displays on the next line even if there is plenty space for it. How can I suppress the new line so that it all shows up on one line? Thanks!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Description") %>
        <i title="Created By Me" style="<%# Eval("CreatedByMe").Equals(true) ? "color: blue": "display:none" %>" class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this so it may be part of your CSS. It shows up on one line for me. However, have you tried literally putting it on the same line in your markup? `<%# Eval("Description") %><i title="Created ...`

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to make a difference. Interestingly I have a couple different UI tabs in for this grid and in some tabs it shows up correctly and in others it line breaks.

Comment: So on closer inspection I noted it is line breaking in the description field on one tab which is typed multiple line of text and then on another tab it is in the title field which is single line of text typed and of course it doesn't line wrap there. So it appears it is wrapping anytime it is able to depending on the type.